# Dense set in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Is $A=\lbrace{ \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace}$ dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology ?

I think it is dense because all infinite subspace are dense sets under cofinite topology but I don't know how to prove.

Comment: A set is dense if its closure is the whole space. And the closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing it. To begin, what are the closed sets of $\mathbb R$ in this topology?

Comment: @ThomasShelby check my latest edit

Comment: @lEm the closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ if its complement is open.

Comment: By definition of cofinite topology, when is a set open? If you can answer this, then you know precisely when is a set closed. Then you should be able to tell what is the smallest of such set that contains $A$.